# Probability that the experiment was performed using given die

Tags: probability, statistics

I have coin $A$ and coin $B$, and probabilities of obtaining heads are 
$\theta_A=0.79$ for coin $A$ and $\theta_B=0.58$ for coin $B$. Given that the result of the experiment of $10$ tosses of one of the two coin was $HTTHHHTTHT$ which coin is more likely to produce it.

I have met this problem when taking expectation maximisation module. I am really struggling to understand how to use empirical observation to calculate the chances of using each die.

Comment: Well, the probability of getting exactly $5$ heads with $A$ is $\binom {10}5\times .79^5\times .21^5=0.031668863$ while the same calculation for $B$ yields $0.216165788$ so...

Comment: Interesting dice, which have the two sides "head" and "tail". I would prefer coins.

Comment: I have no idea what I was thinking about when typing this out. Thanks callculus. And thank you lulu.